# Django file validation with custom validator doesn't work as I expected

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a form with some data and a file that needs to be uploaded. I want to limit the file size to 5MB and I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I've tried using a validators.py file and run .validate() and .run_validators() but I didn't make it work. I will show you some code.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Oferta, CV
from django.contrib import messages

# Create your views here.
def incarcareoferta(req):
    context = {
        'title': "Incarcare oferta de munca | Best DAVNIC73"
    }
    if req.method == 'POST':
        try:
            COR = req.POST['COR']
            denumireMeserie = req.POST['denumireMeserie']
            locuri = req.POST['numarLocuri']
            agentEconomic = req.POST['agentEconomic']
            adresa = req.POST['adresa']
            dataExpirare = req.POST['expirareOferta']
            experientaSolicitata = req.POST['experienta']
            studiiSolicitate = req.POST['studii']
            judet = req.POST['judet']
            telefon = req.POST['telefon']
            emailContact = req.POST['email']
            cerere = Oferta(solicitant=req.user, cor=COR, denumireMeserie=denumireMeserie, locuri=locuri, agentEconomic=agentEconomic, adresa=adresa, dataExpirare=dataExpirare, experientaSolicitata=experientaSolicitata, studiiSolicitate=studiiSolicitate, judet=judet, telefon=telefon, emailContact=emailContact)
            cerere.save()
        except:
            messages.error(req, 'Nu ai completat corect campurile sau unul din ele este liber!')            
    return render(req, "../templates/pagini/incarcare-oferta-de-munca.html", context)

def incarcarecv(req):
    context = {
        'title': "Incarcare CV | Best DAVNIC73"
    }
    if req.method == 'POST':
        try:
            nume = req.POST['nume']
            prenume = req.POST['prenume']
            telefon = req.POST['telefon']
            email = req.POST['email']
            cv = req.FILES['CV']
            try:
                cv_upload = CV(
                solicitant=req.user,
                nume=nume,
                prenume=prenume,
                telefon=telefon,
                emailContact=email
                )
                CV.run_validators()
                cv_upload.CV.save(cv.name, cv)
                cv_upload.save()
            except (ValueError):
                messages.error(req, 'Formularul nu a fost incarcat!')
                messages.info(req, 'Verifica daca esti logat, sau daca ai completat campurile corect!')
            except:
                messages.error(req, 'Formularul nu a fost incarcat. Ceva nu a functionat corect!')
        except:
            messages.error(req, 'Nu ai completat corect campurile sau unul din ele este liber!')
    return render(req, "../templates/pagini/incarcare-cv.html", context)
```

validators.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


def validate_file_size(value):
    filesize=value.size

    if filesize > 524288000:
        print('too big')
        raise ValidationError(_('Invalid value'), code='invalid')
    else:
        return value
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .validators import validate_file_size

# Create your models here.
class Oferta(models.Model):
    solicitant = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dataSolicitare = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    cor = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    denumireMeserie = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    locuri = models.IntegerField()
    agentEconomic = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    adresa = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    dataExpirare = models.DateField()
    experientaSolicitata = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    studiiSolicitate = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    judet = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    telefon = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    emailContact = models.EmailField(max_length=40)
    rezolvata = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.cor

class CV(models.Model):
    solicitant = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dataUploadCV = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    nume = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    prenume = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    telefon = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    emailContact = models.EmailField(max_length=40)
    CV = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%d/%m/%Y', validators=[validate_file_size])
    rezolvata = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nume + " " + self.prenume + ": " + str(self.CV)
```

But it doesn't do anything. I also tried

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Oferta, CV
from django.contrib import messages

# Create your views here.
def incarcareoferta(req):
    context = {
        'title': "Incarcare oferta de munca | Best DAVNIC73"
    }
    if req.method == 'POST':
        try:
            COR = req.POST['COR']
            denumireMeserie = req.POST['denumireMeserie']
            locuri = req.POST['numarLocuri']
            agentEconomic = req.POST['agentEconomic']
            adresa = req.POST['adresa']
            dataExpirare = req.POST['expirareOferta']
            experientaSolicitata = req.POST['experienta']
            studiiSolicitate = req.POST['studii']
            judet = req.POST['judet']
            telefon = req.POST['telefon']
            emailContact = req.POST['email']
            cerere = Oferta(solicitant=req.user, cor=COR, denumireMeserie=denumireMeserie, locuri=locuri, agentEconomic=agentEconomic, adresa=adresa, dataExpirare=dataExpirare, experientaSolicitata=experientaSolicitata, studiiSolicitate=studiiSolicitate, judet=judet, telefon=telefon, emailContact=emailContact)
            cerere.save()
        except:
            messages.error(req, 'Nu ai completat corect campurile sau unul din ele este liber!')            
    return render(req, "../templates/pagini/incarcare-oferta-de-munca.html", context)

def incarcarecv(req):
    context = {
        'title': "Incarcare CV | Best DAVNIC73"
    }
    if req.method == 'POST':
        try:
            nume = req.POST['nume']
            prenume = req.POST['prenume']
            telefon = req.POST['telefon']
            email = req.POST['email']
            cv = req.FILES['CV']
            try:
                cv_upload = CV(
                solicitant=req.user,
                nume=nume,
                prenume=prenume,
                telefon=telefon,
                emailContact=email
                )
                cv_upload.CV.save(cv.name, cv)
                cv_upload.save()
            except (ValueError):
                messages.error(req, 'Formularul nu a fost incarcat!')
                messages.info(req, 'Verifica daca esti logat, sau daca ai completat campurile corect!')
            except (invalid):
                messages.error(req, 'File is too big!')
            except:
                messages.error(req, 'Formularul nu a fost incarcat. Ceva nu a functionat corect!')
        except:
            messages.error(req, 'Nu ai completat corect campurile sau unul din ele este liber!')
    return render(req, "../templates/pagini/incarcare-cv.html", context)
```

Because I thought the error will be the one from validators.py

Nothing worked.

So how can I limit the file size using this code?
What am I doing wrong right now?
Thanks.

Comment: By default, Django does *not* validate the fields, a `ModelForm` will call the validators defined in the model.

Comment: So that means I didn't understand the idea of validators right? I don't want to validate the fields (I suppose you are talking about the fields of the file), I just want to check the file size and throw an error if it's too big.

Comment: no, I'm talking about the fields of your `CV` model. One of the fields is that file, and since you attached a validator to it, by validating that model, we thus validate that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation on validators [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run) says:

> (...) Note that **validators will not be run automatically when you
>   save a model**, but if you are **using a `ModelForm`, it will run your
>   validators** on any fields that are included in your form. (...)

You can manually validate your model by calling [**`Model.full_clean(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean):

```
try:
    cv_upload = CV(
        solicitant=req.user,
        nume=nume,
        prenume=prenume,
        telefon=telefon,
        emailContact=email
    )
    cv_upload.CV.save(cv.name, cv)
    cv_upload.full_clean()
    cv_upload.save()
except (ValueError):
    messages.error(req, 'Formularul nu a fost incarcat!')
    messages.info(req, 'Verifica daca esti logat, sau daca ai completat campurile corect!')
except (invalid):
    messages.error(req, 'File is too big!')
except:
    messages.error(req, 'Formularul nu a fost incarcat. Ceva nu a functionat corect!')
```

But I really advise to use a [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm) here. Model forms are easier to manager, these remove a large amount of boilerplate, and furthermore if the form is invalid, these will return the batch of errors, not a single one.

Comment: It doesn't work. I got rid of all the try-except blocks so I could get the error. I got this:'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'full_clean'.

Comment: As to why I'm not using a ModelForm: as far as I know they are good when the files needs to have specific rows. My file doesn't need to, it only needs to have max 5MB.

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu: sorry that should be `cv_upload`, since that is basically the `CV` object, one extra reason for a `ModelForm` :)

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu: a `ModelForm` has *nothing* to do with specific rows of files, they do not have anything to do with a file in general. A `Form` is simply a layer between the view and the model that heps validating the fields of the model object, generating error messages, etc.. Most of the times, you only need to specify the model itself. I strongly suggest that you read the documentation on `ModelField`s before you decide.

Comment: It works now. So I didn't understand how ModelForms at all. I will check the docs and I might use one, because you said there are better. For now, do you know why don't I get the "file is too big" message? I get messages.error(req, 'Nu ai completat corect campurile sau unul din ele este liber!') everytime.

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu: `except (invalid):` makes no sense, you should use `except ValidationError`:, but I would consider that not very "stable" as well, since if you later add extra validators (like a non-empty name), then all these things can raise a `ValiationError`.

Comment: I thought that code='invalid' in validators.py defines the name of the exception.

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu: no, Python's `try`-`except` can only disambiguate on the type of the exception, not on the content (of course you can add `if`s in the `except`, but that would further complicate the algorithm).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.